# Tkinter se ralentiza cuando utiizo Hilos en Python

Tags: python, mysql, tkinter, hilos, socket

Estoy tratando de crear un chat por sockets, y me está funcionando. Mi problema es que estoy intentando implementar una opción para cerrar sesión y volver a aparecer con la ventana de login (un Log out), que está en el menú de barra "Cerrar sesión". He intentado de varias formas volver a abrir esta ventana.

Ya tengo un método para salir del programa al presionar el menú "Salir". Para el menú "Cerrar sesión" creé el método "cerrarSesión", abrir la ventana login y cerrar la ventana main, pero cuando se abre nuevamente la ventana de Logout el programa me va extremadamente lento.

Este es el código para el cliente. Pueden notar que tuve que repetir código de la clase login y logout porque no supe como poder llamar de vuelta  la ventana de la clase VentanaLogin:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter import scrolledtext as scroll
from pymysql import IntegrityError
import time
import conexion

class Login:
    def __init__(self, ventanaLogin):
        self.ventanaLogin = ventanaLogin
        self.ventanaLogin.title('Iniciar sesión')
        self.database = conexion.Database()
        
        # --- Frame Login ---
        loginFrame = Frame(self.ventanaLogin, bg='grey8')
        loginFrame.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # --- Centrando ventana ---
        width = 400
        height = 480
        anchoPantalla = self.ventanaLogin.winfo_screenwidth()
        largoPantalla = self.ventanaLogin.winfo_screenheight()
        coordenada_x = (anchoPantalla/2) - (width/2)
        coordenada_y = (largoPantalla/2) - (height/2)
        self.ventanaLogin.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{int(coordenada_x)}+{int(coordenada_y)}')

        # --- Entrada y boton de login ---
        tituloLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Programa de chat online', font=('Arial', 20), bg='grey8', fg='white', bd=0)
        tituloLabel.pack(pady=50)
        contraseñaLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Ingrese su nombre de usuario', font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey13', fg='white', bd=0)
        contraseñaLabel.pack()
        self.usuarioEntry = Entry(loginFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0)
        self.usuarioEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        self.usuarioEntry.focus()
        contraseñaLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Ingrese su contraseña', font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey13', fg='white', bd=0)
        contraseñaLabel.pack()
        self.contraseñaEntry = Entry(loginFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0, show='*')
        self.contraseñaEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        loginBoton = Button(loginFrame, text='Iniciar sesión', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Arial', 14), width=15, bd=0, command=lambda:self.login(self))
        loginBoton.pack(pady=(10,0))
        registerLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='¿No tienes una cuenta?', bg='grey13', fg='white', font=('Arial', 10), bd=0)
        registerLabel.pack(pady=(30,10))
        registerBoton = Button(loginFrame, text='Registrarse', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Arial', 14), width=15, bd=0, command=lambda:self.registro(self))
        registerBoton.pack()

        # --- Tecla inicion de sesión ---
        self.usuarioEntry.bind('<Return>', self.login)
        self.contraseñaEntry.bind('<Return>', self.login)

    def login(self, event):
        usuario = self.usuarioEntry.get()
        contraseña = self.contraseñaEntry.get()
        parametros = (usuario, contraseña)
        query = 'SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE nombre = %s AND contraseña = %s'
        peticion = self.database.consulta(query, parametros)
        usuarioLogin = ''
        contraseñaLogin = ''
        for i in peticion:
            usuarioLogin = i[1]
            contraseñaLogin = i[2]
        
        if usuario == usuarioLogin and contraseña == contraseñaLogin:
            if usuario != '' or contraseña != '':
                messagebox.showinfo('Iniciar sesión', 'Ha ingresado con éxito')
                ventanaMain = Main(usuario)
                self.ventanaLogin.withdraw()
            else:
                messagebox.showerror('Iniciar sesión', 'Ingrese los campos requeridos')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Iniciar sesión', 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos')

    def registro(self, event):
        ventanaRegistro = VentanaRegistro()
        self.ventanaLogin.withdraw()
        

class Main:
    def __init__(self, usuario):
        self.ventanaMain = Toplevel()
        self.usuario = usuario
        self.ventanaMain.title('Chat')
        self.ventanaMain.resizable(0,0)

        # --- Frame main ---
        self.mainFrame = Frame(self.ventanaMain, bg='grey8')
        self.mainFrame.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # --- Centrando ventana ---
        width = 400
        height = 550
        anchoPantalla = self.ventanaMain.winfo_screenwidth()
        largoPantalla = self.ventanaMain.winfo_screenheight()
        coordenada_x = (anchoPantalla/2) - (width/2)
        coordenada_y = (largoPantalla/2) - (height/2)
        self.ventanaMain.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{int(coordenada_x)}+{int(coordenada_y)}')

        # --- Texto del chat ---
        self.texto = scroll.ScrolledText(self.mainFrame)
        self.texto.pack(padx=20, pady=(20, 10))
        self.textoLabel = Label(self.mainFrame, text='Escribir mensaje', font=('Arial', 12), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        self.textoLabel.pack()
        self.textoEntry = Entry(self.mainFrame, font=('Arial', 12), bd=0, width=30)
        self.textoEntry.pack(pady=5)
        self.textoEntry.focus()
        self.textoButton = Button(self.mainFrame, text='Enviar', font=('Arial', 12), bg='white', fg='grey8', bd=0, width=20, command=lambda:self.enviarMensaje(self))
        self.textoButton.pack(pady=5)

        # --- Menus ---
        self.menu = Menu(self.mainFrame)
        self.ventanaMain.config(menu=self.menu)
        self.sesionMenu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='Sesión', menu=self.sesionMenu)
        self.sesionMenu.add_command(label='Cerrar sesión', command=self.cerrarSesion)
        self.archivoMenu = Menu(self.menu, tearoff=0)
        self.menu.add_cascade(label='Archivo', menu=self.archivoMenu)
        self.sesionMenu.add_command(label='Salir', command=self.salirPrograma)
    
        self.textoEntry.bind('<Return>', self.enviarMensaje)

        try:
            # --- Conexión servidor ---
            self.socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
            self.socket.connect(('127.0.0.1', 5050))

            # --- Threads ---
            self.hiloRecibir = Thread(target=self.recibirMensaje)
            self.hiloRecibir.start()

        except ConnectionRefusedError:
            messagebox.showerror('Conexión', 'El servidor no se encuentra activo actualmente. Intente en otro momento')
            self.ventanaMain.destroy()
            self.ventanaMain.protocol('WM_DELETEN_WINDOW', self.procesoFinalizado)
    
    def enviarMensaje(self, event):
        mensaje = f'{self.usuario}: {self.textoEntry.get()}'
        self.socket.send(mensaje.encode('utf-8'))
        self.textoEntry.delete(0, END)
        self.texto.insert(INSERT, mensaje + '\n')
    
    def recibirMensaje(self):
        self.texto.config(state='normal')
        while True:
            try:
                mensaje = self.socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
                if mensaje == '@username':
                    self.socket.send(self.usuario.encode('utf-8'))
                elif mensaje == '@otroDispositivo':
                    messagebox.showerror('Conexión', 'Ya has iniciado sesión al servidor')
                    self.ventana.destroy()
                    self.hiloRecibir.join()
                elif mensaje == '@error':
                    messagebox.showerror('Conexión', 'El servidor ha sido desconectado')
                    self.ventana.destroy()
                    self.hiloRecibir.join()
                else:
                    self.texto.insert(INSERT, mensaje + '\n')
            except:
                break
    
    def salirPrograma(self):
        self.socket.send('@desconexion'.encode('utf-8'))
        self.ventanaMain.destroy()

    def cerrarSesion(self):
        self.ventanaMain.withdraw()
        self.socket.send('@desconexion'.encode('utf-8'))
        time.sleep(5)
        ventanaLogin = Logout()


class Logout:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventanaLogin = Toplevel()
        self.ventanaLogin.title('Iniciar sesión')
        self.database = conexion.Database()
        
        # --- Frame Login ---
        loginFrame = Frame(self.ventanaLogin, bg='grey8')
        loginFrame.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)

        # --- Centrando ventana ---
        width = 400
        height = 480
        anchoPantalla = self.ventanaLogin.winfo_screenwidth()
        largoPantalla = self.ventanaLogin.winfo_screenheight()
        coordenada_x = (anchoPantalla/2) - (width/2)
        coordenada_y = (largoPantalla/2) - (height/2)
        self.ventanaLogin.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{int(coordenada_x)}+{int(coordenada_y)}')

        # --- Entrada y boton de login ---
        tituloLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Programa de chat online', font=('Arial', 20), bg='grey8', fg='white', bd=0)
        tituloLabel.pack(pady=50)
        contraseñaLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Ingrese su nombre de usuario', font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey13', fg='white', bd=0)
        contraseñaLabel.pack()
        self.usuarioEntry = Entry(loginFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0)
        self.usuarioEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        self.usuarioEntry.focus()
        contraseñaLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='Ingrese su contraseña', font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey13', fg='white', bd=0)
        contraseñaLabel.pack()
        self.contraseñaEntry = Entry(loginFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0, show='*')
        self.contraseñaEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        loginBoton = Button(loginFrame, text='Iniciar sesión', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Arial', 14), width=15, bd=0, command=lambda:self.login(self))
        loginBoton.pack(pady=(10,0))
        registerLabel = Label(loginFrame, text='¿No tienes una cuenta?', bg='grey13', fg='white', font=('Arial', 10), bd=0)
        registerLabel.pack(pady=(30,10))
        registerBoton = Button(loginFrame, text='Registrarse', bg='white', fg='black', font=('Arial', 14), width=15, bd=0, command=lambda:self.registro(self))
        registerBoton.pack()

        # --- Tecla inicion de sesión ---
        self.usuarioEntry.bind('<Return>', self.login)
        self.contraseñaEntry.bind('<Return>', self.login)

    def login(self, event):
        usuario = self.usuarioEntry.get()
        contraseña = self.contraseñaEntry.get()
        parametros = (usuario, contraseña)
        query = 'SELECT * FROM USUARIOS WHERE nombre = %s AND contraseña = %s'
        peticion = self.database.consulta(query, parametros)
        usuarioLogin = ''
        contraseñaLogin = ''
        for i in peticion:
            usuarioLogin = i[1]
            contraseñaLogin = i[2]
        
        if usuario == usuarioLogin and contraseña == contraseñaLogin:
            if usuario != '' or contraseña != '':
                messagebox.showinfo('Iniciar sesión', 'Ha ingresado con éxito')
                ventanaMain = Main(usuario)
                self.ventanaLogin.destroy()
            else:
                messagebox.showerror('Iniciar sesión', 'Ingrese los campos requeridos')
        else:
            messagebox.showerror('Iniciar sesión', 'Usuario o contraseña incorrectos')
    
    def registro(self, event):
        ventanaRegistro = VentanaRegistro()
        self.ventanaLogin.withdraw()


class VentanaRegistro:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ventana = Toplevel()
        self.ventana.title('Registro')
        self.ventana.resizable(0,0)
        self.database = conexion.Database()

        # --- Centrando ventana ---
        width = 400
        height = 450
        anchoPantalla = self.ventana.winfo_screenwidth()
        largoPantalla = self.ventana.winfo_screenheight()
        coordenada_x = (anchoPantalla/2) - (width/2)
        coordenada_y = (largoPantalla/2) - (height/2)
        self.ventana.geometry(f'{width}x{height}+{int(coordenada_x)}+{int(coordenada_y)}')

        # --- Frame register ---
        datosFrame = Frame(self.ventana, bg='grey8')
        datosFrame.pack(side='top', fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
        
        # --- Entrada y boton de registro ---
        tituloLabel = Label(datosFrame, text='Registro de usuario', font=('Arial', 20), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        tituloLabel.pack(pady=30)
        nombreLabel = Label(datosFrame, text='Ingrese su nombre',font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        nombreLabel.pack()
        self.nombreEntry = Entry(datosFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0)
        self.nombreEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        self.nombreEntry.focus()
        contraseñaLabel = Label(datosFrame, text='Ingrese su contraseña',font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        contraseñaLabel.pack()
        self.contraseñaEntry = Entry(datosFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0, show='*')
        self.contraseñaEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        correoLabel = Label(datosFrame, text='Ingrese su correo electrónico',font=('Arial', 13), bg='grey8', fg='white')
        correoLabel.pack()
        self.correoEntry = Entry(datosFrame, font=('Arial', 13), width=25, bd=0)
        self.correoEntry.pack(pady=(5,10))
        registroBoton = Button(datosFrame, text='Confirmar registro', bg='white', font=('Arial', 14), width=15, bd=0, command=lambda:self.registarUsuario(self))
        registroBoton.pack(pady=5)

        # --- Teclas para registro ---
        self.nombreEntry.bind('<Return>', self.registarUsuario)
        self.contraseñaEntry.bind('<Return>', self.registarUsuario)
        self.correoEntry.bind('<Return>', self.registarUsuario)

    def registarUsuario(self, event):
        try:
            usuario = self.nombreEntry.get()
            contraseña = self.contraseñaEntry.get()
            correo = self.correoEntry.get()

            # --- Todos los campos deben estar completados ---
            if usuario == '' or contraseña == '' or correo == '':
                messagebox.showerror('Registro', 'Ingrese los campos requeridos')
            else:
                # --- Query INSERT --- 
                parametros = (usuario, contraseña, correo)
                query = 'INSERT INTO USUARIOS (nombre, contraseña, correo) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)'
                self.database.consulta(query, parametros)
                messagebox.showinfo('Registro', 'Usuario registrado exitosamente')
                ventanaLogout = Logout()
                self.ventana.destroy()
        except IntegrityError:
            messagebox.showerror('Registro', 'Ya existe una cuenta con este nombre.')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    login = Login(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Este es el código del servidor:

```
from socket import *
from threading import Thread

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5050

# --- Crear socket ---
server = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))

# --- Servidor modo escucha ---
server.listen()
print(f'Server running on {HOST}:{PORT}')

clientes = []
usernames = []

# --- Broadcast a todos los clientes excepto el sender ---
def broadcast(mensaje, _cliente):
    for i in clientes:
        if i != _cliente:
            i.send(mensaje)

# --- Maneja los mensajes recibidos de los clientes y los replica a todos mediante broadcast() ---
def manejoMensajes(cliente):
    while True:
        mensaje = cliente.recv(1024)
        if mensaje == b'@desconexion':
            index = clientes.index(cliente)
            username = usernames[index]
            mensaje = f"{username} se ha desconectado".encode("utf-8")
            print(f"{username} se ha desconectado")
            broadcast(mensaje, cliente)
            clientes.remove(cliente)
            usernames.remove(username)
            cliente.close()
            break
        else:
            broadcast(mensaje, cliente)
        

# --- Recibe todas las conexiones de los clientes y los guarda en su lista ---
def recibirConexiones():
    while True:
        try:
            cliente, address = server.accept()
            cliente.send('@username'.encode('utf-8'))
            username = cliente.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')
            if username in usernames:
                print(f'{username} ha intentado conectarse desde otro dispositivo')
                cliente.send('@otroDispositivo'.encode('utf-8'))
            else:
                clientes.append(cliente)
                usernames.append(username)
                print(f'{username} entró al servidor')
                mensaje = f'{username} ha entrado al chat'.encode('utf-8')
                broadcast(mensaje, cliente)
                cliente.send('Conectado al servidor'.encode('utf-8'))
                thread = Thread(target=manejoMensajes, args=(cliente, ))
                thread.start()
        except:
            for i in clientes:
                cliente.send('@error'.encode('utf-8'))
            print('Ha ocurrido un error. El servidor ha sido desconectado')

recibirConexiones()
```

La autenticación lo estoy haciendo mediante una Bd de MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Tu código no me funciona, pero puedes intentar crear dos Frames y utilizar `tkraise()`. Esto sirve para cambiar entre Frames, te dejo una página donde lo explican bien y con un ejemplo.

https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkraise/